# Difference operator defined in Probability by Shiryaev

Tags: probability-theory

[image]

This is from Shiryaev's book Probability page 157

$F$ acts on $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ how does an operator on $R^{n}$ act on $F$? 
Im trying to do a simple exersice afterwards i.e showing that
$\Delta_{a_{1},b_{1}}\cdots \Delta_{a_{n},b_{n}}F=P((a,b])$

I try to do this by iterating and using distributive law on the two $F's$ I get. But this does not give me what I want.
Am I interperting this defintion wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator that has been defined possesses no meaning by itself unless it acts on a function. So to say, when Shiryaev writes $\Delta_{a_{i},b_{i}}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, what he actually means is that this operator, when acted on a function $F:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, produces the result mentioned.

This is very similar to the del operator $\nabla$. By itself, it possesses no meaning. When acted on a scalar function, it gives a vector (to be precise, the vector of maximum rate of change of the function at any point).

Comment: inst "del" then a operator from the set of scalar functions to the set of n-tuples?

Comment: Yes. It is in the same spirit that Shiryaev defines $\Delta_{a_{i},b_{i}}$ also. Think of $\Delta_{a_{i},b_{i}}$ as acting on an $F:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then, there is no confusion.

Comment: well there is since it donst add up in the end for me. $\Delta_{a_{1},b_{1}}\Delta_{a_{2},b_{2}}F \ne P((a,b])$ when doing
$\Delta_{a_{1},b_{1}}(F(x,b_{2})-F(x,a_{2}))..$

Comment: It does. $F(.)$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Now, $\Delta_{a_{1},b_{1}}$ tells you to only work on the $x_{1}$ coordinate of $F$ and to not touch the other coordinates.

Comment: $\Delta_{a_{1},b_{1}}\Delta_{a_{2},b_{2}}F(x,y)=F(b_{1},b_{2})-F(a_{1},b_{2})-F(b_{1},a_{2})+F(a_{1},a_{2})?$

Comment: Yes. That's right

Comment: and $P(a,b]=F(b_{1},b_{2})-F(a_{1},a_{2})$ ?

Comment: If $(a,b]$ is a rectangle in$\mathbb{R}^2, (a,b]=(a_1,b_1] \times (a_2,b_2]$.

Then $ P((a,b])=P( (a_1,b_1] \times (a_2,b_2]  )=F(a_1 < x_1 \leq b_1, a_2 < x_2 \leq b_2)=F(b_1,b_2) -F(a_1,b_2) -F(b_1,a_2) +F(a_1,a_2)$